# displaying multiple select box .change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two select boxes that display data based on the selection. Both work find with the exception that my `script` code will only allow for one of the select boxes to display data at a time. I added an additional if statement but I believe the `.change` is cause only one select box to remain displayed at a time

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".pizza").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".pizza").hide();
      }
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".soda").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".soda").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Choose Soda</option>
  <option value="food-s">pepsi</option>

</select>
<select>
  <option>Choose Pizza</option>
  <option value="food-p">cheese</option>

</select>
<p> Display </p>
<div class="food-s soda">
  <strong>Choose a Soda:</strong>
  <ul>
    <li>Coke</li>
    <li>Pepsi</li>
    <li>Diet</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="food-p pizza">
  <strong>Choose a Pizza:</strong>
  <ul>
    <li>Cheese</li>
    <li>Extra Cheese</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: All your options have the same value, how is this supposed to do something dependent on which option you selected. `if (optionValue)` will always be true since you have no empty values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have separate event handlers, one for the soda dropdown and the other for the pizza dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#soda").change(function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).val();
    if (optionValue) {
      $(".soda").not("." + optionValue).hide();
      $("." + optionValue).show();
    } else {
      $(".soda").hide();
    }
  }).change();

  $("select#pizza").change(function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).val();
    if (optionValue) {
      $(".pizza").not("." + optionValue).hide();
      $("." + optionValue).show();
    } else {
      $(".pizza").hide();
    }
  }).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="soda">
  <option>Choose Soda</option>
  <option value="food-s">pepsi</option>
</select>
<select id="pizza">
  <option>Choose Pizza</option>
  <option value="food-p">cheese</option>
</select>
<p> Display </p>
<div class="food-s soda">
  <strong>Choose a Soda:</strong>
  <ul>
    <li>Coke</li>
    <li>Pepsi</li>
    <li>Diet</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="food-p pizza">
  <strong>Choose a Pizza:</strong>
  <ul>
    <li>Cheese</li>
    <li>Extra Cheese</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```